Formal demonstration of bound and continuous spectra in a 1D potential problem
I understand that if a particle is in a confining potential, its spectrum is discrete. When the particle's energy is greater than the potential, the spectrum becomes continuous, allowing the particle to move in both directions (left and right). Now, if the potential forms a "barrier" that blocks motion in only one direction, I get that the spectrum remains continuous, but the particle can only move in the opposite direction to the barrier.
In the picture, if $V_{\text{min}} < E <V_1$ there are bound states, if $E>V_2$ there are continuum states degenerated with left and right traveling waves and in the other case the
energy spectrum is continuous and none of the energy eigenvalues is degenerate (more or less, you know).

Could anyone help me with a formal demonstration of this facts? Any hints or references on how to approach this mathematically would be greatly appreciated!
